# Multiple action form

Tags: ruby, forms

I'm trying to create a complex (from my opinion) form, but the process is going very hard.
I want the form to have 4 elements:

- A list [of subjects] and a button [to delete selected subject from list];
- A button and an associated input field ["Add subject" and field to add it, respectively];

I think a single form wouldn't be enough, and first of all I should divide my elements in to two forms (or even nested forms - which I really don't know how to do). But what's the right way?

Even though I'm trying to make a single form with a simple add action, a receive an error [**undefined method 
`subjects_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x485934c**]. I've created the model **Subjects** simply by 'script/generate model' command (i.e. not by the generate scaffold). Maybe this is the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essence it sounds like your view needs two forms, one to add a Subject and the other to delete a Subject via a RESTful controller. Don't forget to specify your subject resources in your routes.rb file. Perhaps if you included some code here it would be easier for others to help.

Comment: Thanks, I really forgot to tell routes about the new resource.